# $S = 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + 4^4 +...... + 2019^{2019} + 2020^{2020}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Math lover Fahad was feeling bored during his vacation. So he wrote a sequence in his diary:
$$S_{2020} = 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + 4^4 +...... + 2019^{2019} + 2020^{2020}.$$
If $S$ is divided by $2$, what will be the remainder?

Comment: Just take mod 2 of each term individually, and you'll get
$$
S \mod 2 = 1^1 + 0^2 + 1^3 + 0^3 + \ldots + 1^{2019} + 0^{2020}
$$

Comment: Consider it mod 2 and count the number of “1”.

Comment: -1 For the title.

Comment: @Matti P. But if instead
$$
S = 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 
$$
then 
$$
(S \mod 2) = (14 \mod 2) = 0
$$
but
$$
(1\mod 2) + (9\mod 2) = 2
$$

Comment: Please give a title that show a math question. You need to be specific.

Comment: @Mikal You are correct; $2 \equiv 0 \mod 2$. So it's all consistent.

Comment: Ahh of course, nice!

Answer (score 3):

There are $1010$ odd terms and $1010$ even terms . Each of these $1010$ even terms will give a remainder of $0$ and each of the $1010$ odd terms will give a remainder of $1$.

Therefore, remainder will be equal to the remainder when $1+1+1+1+1+\dots$ ($1010$ terms) is divided by $2$.

Hence the answer will be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Every even number raised to any natural number is even and every odd number raised to any natural number is odd.

Now write even term as $2n_1,2n_2,\dots$ and every odd term as $2k_1+1,2k_2+1,\dots$ and so on.

Separate the even and odd terms and divide by $2$ the answer is now self evident.